# How to parse this XML and store it in Collection

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

i have to parse it and display it in a asp.net webpage

The output should look like this 
[image: Something like this]

### XML

```
 <results id="10157" objectType="ROS" systemName="Constitutional" comments="" systemStatus="" patientPartyId="158641" providerPartyId="145150" patientEncounterId="17137" updatedBy="C144964.U685" updatedDate="2012-04-28T10:13:40" urn="ROS-Constitutional-PatientRosSystemsType-10157" createdDate="" createdBy="" activeFlag="true">
  <symptoms id="10194" systemId="10157" symptomName="Fatigue" updatedBy="C144964.U685" updatedDate="2012-04-28T10:13:19" urn="ROS-Constitutional-Fatigue-PatientSymptomType-10194" createdDate="" createdBy="" activeFlag="true">
    <symptomAttributes id="31393" parentId="10194" className="ObjectAttributeTypeImpl" parentClassName="PatientSymptomType" name="Status" value="C" updatedBy="C144964.U685" updatedDate="2012-04-28T10:13:40" createdBy="" createdDate="" urn="cos-ts-CompanyType-144964-ObjectAttributeType-31393" activeFlag="true"/>
    <symptomAttributes id="31394" parentId="10194" className="ObjectAttributeTypeImpl" parentClassName="PatientSymptomType" name="Comment" value="test123" updatedBy="C144964.U685" updatedDate="2012-04-28T10:13:40" createdBy="" createdDate="" urn="cos-ts-CompanyType-144964-ObjectAttributeType-31394" activeFlag="true"/>
  </symptoms>
  <symptoms id="10195" systemId="10157" symptomName="Fever" updatedBy="C144964.U685" updatedDate="2012-04-28T10:13:19" urn="ROS-Constitutional-Fever-PatientSymptomType-10195" createdDate="" createdBy="" activeFlag="true">
    <symptomAttributes id="31395" parentId="10195" className="ObjectAttributeTypeImpl" parentClassName="PatientSymptomType" name="Status" value="C" updatedBy="C144964.U685" updatedDate="2012-04-28T10:13:40" createdBy="" createdDate="" urn="cos-ts-CompanyType-144964-ObjectAttributeType-31395" activeFlag="true"/>
    <symptomAttributes id="31396" parentId="10195" className="ObjectAttributeTypeImpl" parentClassName="PatientSymptomType" name="Comment" value="testing" updatedBy="C144964.U685" updatedDate="2012-04-28T10:13:40" createdBy="" createdDate="" urn="cos-ts-CompanyType-144964-ObjectAttributeType-31396" activeFlag="true"/>
  </symptoms>
</results>
<results>................</results>
<results>................</results>
........ so on
```

This is the xml i got from server.
i have to parse this and store it in a collection, i'm not getting any idea how to store it in a collection or something. Because there would be multiple `results` tags and each `result` tag has its own values and sub tags

Normally i parse the response and store it in a `List<Dictionary<,>>` if XML is two level. But here that approach will not work.

I have to store it in one variable(List or something) and only some attributes of the `elements` i have to store. like in `results` =>(id,sytemName,comments) in `symptoms` =>(id,symptomName) and in `symptomAttributes` => (name,value)...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend:

1. Defining a struct ("record") for each "symptom"
2. Putting your symptoms in a "List"
3. I'm not sure what a "ROS" or "Constitutional" mean, but I suspect your "symptoms" list might be associated with a "patient".  And that you should also have a "struct" for patient records, and a "List" (containing the "symptoms" sublist).

Comment: ROS means ReviewOfSystems, and Constitutional means the type of decease. that's nice approach but i have to store some attributes of the results tag also